# openLDAP get login attempt on a user

Tags: ldap, openldap

I try to get information from users on a new openldap server,
I want to get the current count of login attempt,
but the only thing I get from the internet is an attribute named 'badPwdCount'  but it's only for Microsoft AD.

If anybody know it, please tell m, or if is there  a good documentation about the hidden attributs that we can't get with a simple '*'.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install and configure the [`ppolicy` overlay](http://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-ppolicy&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=OpenLDAP+2.3-Release), and then query the operational attribute `pwdFailureTime`. The number of values of this attribute is the count of the most recent login failures. When the user logs in successfully it is cleared.